# Are questions about specific plot details on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are already three of them:
[Did the FBI know about the mole in the police department and did they interfere with the investigation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/10/41)
https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/5/41
[What does the ending of The Tree of Life mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/6/41)

I'm sure more are going to come, and they don't strike me as directed towards experts. What should our policy on them be?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [top-voted example question during the definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies/3702#3702), yes, questions about plot details are on topic.

Comment: That's what I used for guidance on appropriateness for one of the above referenced questions.

Comment: I just fear that this kind of questions will drown out everything else.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: That doesn't seem to be the case on SciFi where the same types of questions are allowed.

Comment: @Flimzy, is it ok to tag them with something like (plot-details) then?

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: My personal view is such a tag would be practically meaningless. Any question not about the making of the movie would have that tag. If you haven't already, I suggest browsing some of the questions at [SciFi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions). Arguably 9 of their top 10 questions are about "plot details" (some in a general sense, of explaining something about the entire universe in which the story takes place), and they don't have such a tag, nor do I sense they feel there's much of a problem.  My suggestion: Wait at least a few days and see how things pan out.

Answer (score 5):

What would be the point of a movie QnA if you can't ask questions about the plot of a movie?

Answer (score 2):

Like others I don't see the point in not being able to discuss plot points here.  Is it more that you have concerns about questions about interpretation.  If so, I have some sympathy with your concern, interpretation questions are unfortunately rather open ended for a QnA forum, but I still think it is fair game to ask them here.

You say that they are not questions to 'experts' - but someone may have watched Inception 20 times and read about it, who can provide more enlightened commentary about it than someone who has only just watched it once.  For instance the Inception question raises the point about Cobb's Totem before he inherited his wife's - something that I had not considered before.  The question is phrased in a very open manner rather than specifying some specific area of interpretation - but I don't overall the forum is better served with them than without.